# How marklogic compute weight to calculate score for a document

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9, marklogic-7

I am exploring relevance info to get information about the factor which influence scoring in Marklogic.

```
<qry:relevance-info xmlns:qry="http://marklogic.com/cts/query">
  <qry:score
    formula="(256*scoreSum/weightSum)+(256*qualityWeight*documentQuality)"
    computation="(256*1274/4)+(256*1*0)">81536</qry:score>
..
</qry:relevance>
```

Does anyone have idea about weightSum factor?

What are the things Marklogic consider to compute the value for weightSum.

Answer (score 1):

## [Using Weights to Influence Scores](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance#id_22791)

> Use a weight in a query sub-expression to either boost or lower the sub-expression contribution to the relevance score.
>
> For example, you can specify weights for leaf-level `cts:query` constructors, such as [`cts:word-query`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:word-query) and [`cts:element-value-query`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-query); for details, see [XQuery and XSLT Reference Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery). You can also specify weights in the equivalent Search API abstractions, such as the structured query constructs `value-query` and `word-constraint-query`, or when defining a word or value constraint in query options.
>
> **The default weight is 1.0.** Use the following guidelines for choosing custom weights:
>
> - To boost the score contribution, set the weight higher than 1.0.
> - To lower the score contribution, set the weight between 0 and 1.0.
> - To contribute nothing to the score, set the weight to 0.
> - To make the score contribution negative, set the weight to a negative number.
>
> Scores are normalized, so a weight is not an absolute multiplier on the score. Instead, weights indicate how much terms from a given query sub-expression are weighted in comparison to other sub-expressions in the same expression. A weight of 2.0 doubles the contribution to the score for terms that match that query. Similarly, a weight of 0.5 halves the contribution to the score for terms that match that query. In some cases, the score reaches a maximum, so a weight of 2.0 and a weight of 20,000 can yield the same contribution to the score.
>
> Adding weights is particularly useful if you have several components in a query expression, and you want matches for some parts of the expression to be weighted more heavily than other parts. For an example of this, see [Increase the Score for some Terms, Decrease for Others](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/relevance#id_55913).

Comment: Thanks for providing these details. I am looking to get how ML calculate weightSum in equation given above XML. It increases when I add query to the existing query and reduces the total score which is depending upon the weightSum value calculated by the ML.